# how to make datagrid auto scrollable in window application programmatically?

Tags: windows

I want to scroll datagrid's content  according to rowindex which is operating currently.
So user can know which row is actually processing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

[DataGrid.ScrollIntoView(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!